# Create encoder on js

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript on my own and have some experience in Java and Python.
I want to create an encoder that works with 2 sets of alphabets and has a mapping from one to another.
for example:

```
Set1 = (א,ב,ג,ד) Set2 = (ا,ب,ج,د)  
א --> ا  
ב --> ب  
ג --> ج  
ד --> د
```

With java and python it makes sense to work with hashmaps but I'm trying to find some easy and elegant way to create this mapping in JS. I tried working with arrays and indexes but it didn't go so well...
Thanks :)

Comment: can you post what you tried with arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do it:
Create a new Object

```
var dict = new Object();
```

// or the shorthand way

```
var dict = {};
```

// using the Indexer

```
dict["a"] = "B";
```

You can also initialize the Dictionary with Key/Value pairs when creating it if you are using the shorthand method.

```
var dict = {
  A: "a",
  B: "b"
};
```

Here are some examples of using a Function in both Key and Value of a Dictionary:

```
var dict = {};

var f = function() {
  // do something
};

// setup Function as Value
dict['method'] = f;

// setup Function as Key
dict[f] = 'some value';

// execute Function from Value
dict['method']();

var method = dict.method;
method();

// get value for Key
var val = dict[f];
```

You can also use a Set (ECMAScript 6) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
:

```
let mySet = new Set()

mySet.add(1)           // Set [ 1 ]
mySet.add(5)           // Set [ 1, 5 ]
mySet.add(5)           // Set [ 1, 5 ]
mySet.add('some text') // Set [ 1, 5, 'some text' ]
let o = {a: 1, b: 2}
mySet.add(o)

mySet.add({a: 1, b: 2})   // o is referencing a different object, so this is okay
```